# Installed Docker on Mac but can't find the command

Tags: python, docker

On My mac I ran:

```
pip install docker
```

And it seems successfully:

```
Installing collected packages: websocket-client, docker-pycreds, docker
Successfully installed docker-3.4.1 docker-pycreds-0.3.0 websocket-client-0.48.0
```

However, when I run the 'docker' at the terminal, it can't find it:

```
$ docker
-bash: docker: command not found
```

Then I run:

```
$ whereis docker
```

It shows nothing. So how do I get docker to run?

Thanks.

Comment: Anything on Google pop up when you search "Install Docker on Mac"?

Comment: ...or go to the docker website and see how they recommend you install docker?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009138/docker-command-not-found-when-running-on-mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm unsure which instructions you followed to install via `pip`, however `docker-3.4.1` is a very old version, so you have worse issues at foot than your PATH not containing the docker binary.

I recommend undoing your installation via pip and installing Docker for Mac the correct way. I believe the current stable version for MacOS is 18.03.

https://store.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-mac

Answer (score 2):

First go and uninstall whatever you did with `pip uninstall docker`

Then go here https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/ and dowload docker and follow the instructions and install it.